# Get values from HTMLCollection in a dynamically generated table with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having this issue while trying to get values from my table  ( these tds are generated on button click ) and classname added with

```
prdctNameSpace.className = 'subTotal';
```

This is my JS function

```
 var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal');
    console.log(arr.length);

var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
}
console.log(tot);

document.getElementById('totalprod').innerHTML = tot;
```

The output in my HTML is NaN .
The first console.log() is working good because it keeps adding +1 everytime I add new  .
I just can't make the sum of these values.

```js
var addShopList = function() {
  // Ajouter un element au tableau
  var product = document.getElementById("shopList").options[document.getElementById('shopList').selectedIndex].text;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("qte").value;
  var sum = document.getElementById("shopList").value;
  var total = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(sum);

  var tbody = document.querySelector('#sellTable tbody');
  var trproduct = document.createElement('TR');
  tbody.appendChild(trproduct);

  var tbodytr = tbody.lastChild;

  //Making 1st Row
  var prdctNameSpace = document.createElement('TD');
  tbodytr.appendChild(prdctNameSpace);
  //First Row content
  var prdctName = document.createTextNode(product);
  prdctNameSpace.appendChild(prdctName);
  prdctNameSpace.className = 'subTotal';

  var productQteSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productQteSpace);
  //2nd col Content
  var productQte = document.createTextNode(quantity);
  productQteSpace.appendChild(productQte);

  //3rd Col
  var productSinglePriceSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productSinglePriceSpace);
  var productSinglePrice = document.createTextNode(parseInt(sum).toFixed(3) + " DT");
  productSinglePriceSpace.appendChild(productSinglePrice);
  //4th col

  var productTotalPriceSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productTotalPriceSpace);
  var productTotalPrice = document.createTextNode(parseFloat(total).toFixed(3) + " DT");
  productTotalPriceSpace.appendChild(productTotalPrice);

  var productDeleteSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  var productDeletebtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  //tbodytr.appendChild(productDeleteSpace);

  productDeletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn x');
  productDeletebtn.name = 'delrow';
  productDeletebtn.textContent = "X";
  tbodytr.appendChild(productDeletebtn);
  console.log(productDeletebtn.name);
  productDeletebtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'delRowList(this)');


  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal');
  console.log(arr.length);

  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  console.log(tot);
  document.getElementById('totalprod').innerHTML = tot;
}

function emptyQte() {
  if (document.getElementById('qte').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('ajout').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ajout').disabled = false;
  }
}

var delRowList = function(btn2) {
  var delbtn = document.getElementById('sellTable');
  delbtn.deleteRow(btn2.parentNode.rowIndex);
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('ajout');
  btn.addEventListener('click', addShopList);
}

window.addEventListener('load', setupListeners);
```

```html
<select id="shopList" onlick="summ()" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3">
  <option selected disabled="disabled"> Liste Des Produits</option>
  <optgroup label="Femme">
    <option value="40" name="PullVegeta2"> Top Femme Colle V
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Homme">
    <option value="35" name="PullVegeta3">Pull Homme OpenMinded
      <option value="30" name="PullVegeta">Pull Homme Vegeta

  </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="text" id="qte" placeholder="Quantité" onkeyup="emptyQte()" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" required/>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="ajout" disabled>
<table id="sellTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nom Produit</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
      <th scope="col">Prix Unitaire</th>
      <th scope="col">Total Produit</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>

  <tfooter>
    <td colspan="3">Somme Total :</td>
    <td id="totalprod"> DT</td>
    <td> <button>Paiement</button></td>
  </tfooter>
</table>
```

Live Version :  https://jsfiddle.net/ajkpo47L/

Comment: What is `arr[i].value`? Please also provide the associated HTML as a [mcve].

Comment: Can you make a live Stack Snippet illustrating the problem? There isn't enough information here to reproduce the issue.

Comment: More info is needed, specifically example data.

Comment: You need to check that `arr[i].value` is non-empty before adding it to the total.

Comment: I added a live version on fiddle.js please check it.

Comment: Please don't use external code representations like fiddles, codepens etc. **unless the StackOverflow snippet functionality isn't sufficient to demonstrate your issue.** Questions seeking debugging help need to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 3):

`prdctNameSpace` is a `<td>`, not an `<input>`. It doesn't have a `value` property.

You should use `.textContent` rather than `.value` to get the contents.

Also, you're putting the `subTotal` class on the wrong element. You're putting it on the cell with the product name, not the total price of that product.

```js
var addShopList = function() {
  // Ajouter un element au tableau
  var product = document.getElementById("shopList").options[document.getElementById('shopList').selectedIndex].text;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("qte").value;
  var sum = document.getElementById("shopList").value;
  var total = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(sum);

  var tbody = document.querySelector('#sellTable tbody');
  var trproduct = document.createElement('TR');
  tbody.appendChild(trproduct);

  var tbodytr = tbody.lastChild;

  //Making 1st Row
  var prdctNameSpace = document.createElement('TD');
  tbodytr.appendChild(prdctNameSpace);
  //First Row content
  var prdctName = document.createTextNode(product);
  prdctNameSpace.appendChild(prdctName);

  var productQteSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productQteSpace);
  //2nd col Content
  var productQte = document.createTextNode(quantity);
  productQteSpace.appendChild(productQte);

  //3rd Col
  var productSinglePriceSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productSinglePriceSpace);
  var productSinglePrice = document.createTextNode(parseInt(sum).toFixed(3) + " DT");
  productSinglePriceSpace.appendChild(productSinglePrice);
  //4th col

  var productTotalPriceSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  tbodytr.appendChild(productTotalPriceSpace);
  var productTotalPrice = document.createTextNode(parseFloat(total).toFixed(3) + " DT");
  productTotalPriceSpace.className = 'subTotal';
  productTotalPriceSpace.appendChild(productTotalPrice);

  var productDeleteSpace = document.createElement("TD");
  var productDeletebtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  //tbodytr.appendChild(productDeleteSpace);

  productDeletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn x');
  productDeletebtn.name = 'delrow';
  productDeletebtn.textContent = "X";
  tbodytr.appendChild(productDeletebtn);
  console.log(productDeletebtn.name);
  productDeletebtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'delRowList(this)');


  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal');
  console.log(arr.length);

  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].textContent);
    tot += parseFloat(arr[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(tot);
  document.getElementById('totalprod').innerHTML = tot.toFixed(3) + ' DT';
}

function emptyQte() {
  if (document.getElementById('qte').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('ajout').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ajout').disabled = false;
  }
}

var delRowList = function(btn2) {
  var delbtn = document.getElementById('sellTable');
  delbtn.deleteRow(btn2.parentNode.rowIndex);
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('ajout');
  btn.addEventListener('click', addShopList);
}

window.addEventListener('load', setupListeners);
```

```html
<select id="shopList" onlick="summ()" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3">
  <option selected disabled="disabled"> Liste Des Produits</option>
  <optgroup label="Femme">
    <option value="40" name="PullVegeta2"> Top Femme Colle V
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Homme">
    <option value="35" name="PullVegeta3">Pull Homme OpenMinded
      <option value="30" name="PullVegeta">Pull Homme Vegeta

  </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="text" id="qte" placeholder="Quantité" onkeyup="emptyQte()" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" required/>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="ajout" disabled>
<table id="sellTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nom Produit</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
      <th scope="col">Prix Unitaire</th>
      <th scope="col">Total Produit</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>

  <tfooter>
    <td colspan="3">Somme Total :</td>
    <td id="totalprod"> DT</td>
    <td> <button>Paiement</button></td>
  </tfooter>
</table>
```

Comment: inputs are filled by pressing a button which adds a td with some values and makes a total at the end

Comment: Yes , that was the problem. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `parseFloat`, I recommend using the `Number()`constructor, which, for an empty `String`, returns `0` instead of `NaN`:

```js
const total = [...document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal')]
  .map(el=>el.value)
  .reduce((a, v) => a + Number(v), 0);
```

See this snippet for different results `Number()` vs. `parseFloat()`:

```js
const testValues = ['', null, undefined];

for (const value of testValues) {
  console.log(`Number(${value}) returns: ${Number(value)}`);
  console.log(`parseFloat(${value}) returns: ${parseFloat(value)}`);
}
```

Comment: still returning NaN , i guess the problem is with my arr variable , when I console.log(arr) is give me HTMLCollection . maybe using arr[i].value isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Your `parseFloat` function is likely returning `NaN` at some point.

```js
let total = 0
for(const subTotalElem of document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal')) {
    const subTotal = Number.parseFloat(subTotalElem.value)
    if(Number.isNaN(subTotal)) {
      console.warn('Subtotal is not a number: ' + subTotalElem.value)
    } else {
      total += subTotal
    }
}
console.log('Total: ' + total)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Parseable</td>
      <td><input disabled class="subTotal" value="42" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Parseable</td>
      <td><input disabled class="subTotal" value="42.00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Parseable</td>
      <td><input disabled class="subTotal" value="42,00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Not Parseable</td>
      <td><input disabled class="subTotal" value="$42.00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Not Parseable</td>
      <td><input disabled class="subTotal" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it , sorry it was my fault. I put classname for my 1st td in the row , which contains name of product not the price.